# How is the below Ethereum contract function call data is constructed?

Tags: ethereum

0x5537f99e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072268656c6c6f2200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

5537f99e is the function name, which is 'setstring'
2268656c6c6f22 is the argument to the function, which is 'hello',

Please explain how this raw data to a ethereum contract is consturcted. I'm confused at those offsets.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the reference here https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html

if your function is

```
function setstring(string string_value) {
}
```

1. first 4bytes `0x5537f99e`

First 4 bytes of data is derived as the first 4 bytes of the Keccak hash of the ASCII form of the signature `setstring(string)`

2. next 32 bytes `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020`

This means the location of the data part of your string_value, measured in bytes from the start of the arguments block. In this case, the next block

3. next 32 bytes
   `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007`

This means size of your string, 7. `"hello"`

4. next 32 bytes
   `2268656c6c6f2200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

The contents of the `"hello"` encoded in UTF-8.